# Why my bubble sort function of linked list sometimes output a wrong result while sometimes seems like to be an infinite loop?

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I'm trying to write a bubble function of my linked list in C, but this function sometimes outputs a incorrect result while sometimes even get into an infinite loop, can anyone tell me what's wrong with my loop structure?

```
void Sort_list(Node *h) {
    Node *p1 = h->next;
    Node *p2 = p1->next;
    Node *odd = h;
    Node *h1 = p1;
    Node *h2 = p2;
    Node *opp = odd;
    while (p2->next != NULL) {
        while (p2->next != NULL) {
            if (p2->score>p1->score) {
                p1->next = p2->next;
                p2->next = p1;
                odd->next = p2;
                p2 = p1->next;
                odd = odd->next;
                p1 = p1->next;
            } else {
                p2 = p2->next;
                p1 = p1->next;
                odd = odd->next;
            }
        }
        opp = opp->next;
        h1 = h1->next;
        h2 = h2->next;
        p1 = h1;
        p2 = h2;
        odd = opp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used your debugger?

Comment: Tip: Use more descriptive variable names than just `p1` and `h2`. What is `opp` and `odd` meant to mean, for example?

Comment: thank you for your advice,I'll change them.and p1,p2,h1,h2 are used to change the order of the Nodes.

Comment: This excerpt does not have a [mre], voting to close

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your *main*() and data structure *Node*. They may be simple, but simple does not mean error-free. A compilable program is necessary for full testing.

While you did not talk about it, I'm pretty sure you have a segfault waiting to happen with zero-length and single-node list:

```
void Sort_list(Node *h) {
    Node *p1 = h->next; //Check if h is NULL ?
    Node *p2 = p1->next; //Check if h->next is NULL ?
```

This part right here seems strange to me:

```
if (p2->score > p1->score) {
                p1->next = p2->next;
                p2->next = p1;
                odd->next = p2;
                p2 = p1->next; //Did you meant p2->next ?
                odd = odd->next;
                p1 = p1->next;
            }
```

If that's the case, I would rework your loop like this to avoid duplicate code:

```
        while (p2->next != NULL) {
            if (p2->score>p1->score) {
                p1->next = p2->next;
                p2->next = p1;
                odd->next = p2;
              }
              p2 = p2->next;
              p1 = p1->next;
              odd = odd->next;
        }
```

I'm not sure if the second loop will work to ensure that everything is sorted from start to finish. At this point you might need to rework your algorithm: use pen and paper before you start writing code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! I use p2=p1->next because I think the order of p1 and p2 have been changed(if not ,i can use p2=p2->next directly) ,and once i want to move p2 to the next Node I need to make p2=p1->next. by the way h is not NULL, but i didn't store any thing in h,it's the head of the linked list.